# Rails - How does ActiveRecord's save method work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

A newbie question regarding the `ActiveRecord`'s `save` method.
If i have this code (as in rails guide):

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  if @post.save
      redirect_to @post
  else
      .....
  end
end
```

The save method returns the new created `Post` object? How, after the code `@post.save`, rails know how to substitute the `redirect_to @post` with the proper `post_id` (1 or 2 or 3 or ....) to build the link?

Comment: Internally, `url_for` determines the url to redirect to.

Comment: Zabba is spot on  -https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c41f08cefe6fa3747ee79001d9c88dc988e8064d/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to explain it by presenting another piece of code that should make things easy to understand

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user
```

Now `:user` contains the following information based on the User model: id, name, email, telephone.

So that means we have actually assigned to `@user` the above hashes.

The `redirect_to` will retrieve the hashes that is already stored in `@user` and display the new profile page.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

It's an OOP concept.
So, after create, the @post is updated with the id, and everything just works.

Take a look at [this code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L433).

Hope it helps.